# How to call JS functions from Java Applet?

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, applet

Well, this is my trouble:

I have an applet that controlls a magnetic stripe reader and I need to call a JS function when the MSR reads a card to catch the data and submit in a form.
The problem is the applet cannot call JS functions when it is called from a remote PC o server, but locally all the code works fine.
I supposed that is a issue of privileges on the browser.
This is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Applet Prueba</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#AppletPrueba")[0].apOpenPrinter();
        $("#AppletPrueba")[0].apActivaMSR();
    });

    function print()
    {
        $("#AppletPrueba")[0].apPrintCreditInfo();
    }

    function setTxtBox(texto)
    {
        $("#txtBox").val(texto);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <object id      = "AppletPrueba"
            classid = "clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
            width   = "1"
            height  = "1">
        <param name="code" value="applet.AppletJPos.class"/>
        <param name="archive" value="SAppletJPos.jar,Sjpos11021.jar,Sjpos191.jar,SNCRJavaPOS39.jar,SNCRJavaPOSClasses.jar,Sxerces.jar"/>
        <param name="scriptable" value="true"/>
        <param name="mayscript" value="true"/>
        <param name="param0" value="1"/>
        <param name="param1" value="Tienda"/>
        <param name="param2" value="XXX"/>
        <param name="param3" value="RUBEN C. FLORES GARNETT"/>
        <param name="param4" value="09 de Marzo de 2012"/>
        <param name="param5" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param6" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param7" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param8" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param9" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param10" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param11" value="0"/>
        <param name="param12" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param13" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param14" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param15" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param16" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param17" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param18" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param19" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param20" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param21" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param22" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param23" value="0.00"/>
        <param name="param24" value="1"/>
    </object>
    <input type="button" value="Imprime Ticket" onclick="print()" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value="" id="txtBox" />
</body>
```

And that is the way the applet call the JS function:

```
AppletContext appletCtxt = getAppletContext();
```

...

```
appletCtxt.showDocument(new URL("javascript: setTxtBox('" + editedCardId[0] + "')"));
```

I really hope somebody can help me.

(I'm sorry if my english is bad :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle tutorial on the matter would probably be useful.

[Invoking JavaScript Code From an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html)

> The `netscape.javascript.JSObject` class enables Java applets to
>   retrieve a reference to JavaScript objects and interact with the web
>   page.